# What is it called to round a number to a closer integer (not rounding the decimals) (see text for explanation)

Tags: terminology, rounding-unit

Like lets say 412 to 425 or 400 (if the multiples are 25) or 516 to 550 or 500 (if the multiples are 50).

I don't know this is not rounding but how would this go?

Comment: "Round $412$ to the nearest multiple of $25$".

Comment: Are you asking _how_ this can be done or what it's _called_ or something else?

Comment: yeah my question was how is it called so I can find it but I was able to discover it myself (based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553728/6877477) I did round(412/25)*25 and got what I needed, it turned out it is round to the nearest multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably call this "rounding to the nearest (integer) multiple of $n$."  That is, if $n$ is some number (probably I would want it to be a positive integer, or perhaps the reciprocal of an integer, but there is no reason that it should be---any positive real number could work), then we can round a real number $x$ to the nearest multiple of $n$ as follows:

1. Set $x_n$ to be $x$ modulo $n$.  That is, take $m$ to be the largest integer such that $mn \le x$, then set $x_n = x - mn$.
2. If $x_n < n/2$, round $x$ down to $mn$.  If $x_n > n/2$, round $x$ up to $(m+1)n$.  If $x_n = n/2$, round up or down according to some rule (always round up, always round down, banker's rounding, flip a coin, etc).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, you're correct, thank you for the explanation